# Is there a way to add fields onto Django's Sites Framework?

Tags: django, django-sites

I really like the idea of the sites framework for making an application functional across multiple web sites. Is there a way to add fields onto the `Site` object for the database, or should I just create a foreign-key one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use a model with a unique foreign key. Django will add it to Site as a reverse relationship.

Comment: So there's no way of directly associating it so it doesn't have to `join` it in SQL? Otherwise, you've answered my question :)

Comment: @TKKocheran: Without editing contrib.site.models, or replacing contrib.site entirely, no.