# Is there a way to add a ForeignKey to the Site model in Django Sites Framework?

Tags: django, django-sites

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892332/2532070) shows the inverse of what I'm looking for because it allows one `Site` to have many `Asset` objects:

```
# Note: This is not my code. This is opposite of what I want.
# I want the ForeignKey on the Site object.
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Asset(models.Model):
    site = Models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

Is there a way to add the ForeignKey field to the `Site` model, such that one `Asset` can have many `Site` objects? Something like this (non-working) code:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class UpdatedSite(Site):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset)
```

I understand that I could use a `ManyToManyField` but in my case one `Site` object will never have multiple `Asset` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have [Foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) in both directions, ( from Asset to Site and from Site to Asset ) -> this is solved with using pivot table ( Many to Many )

If you just need the relation to hold many assets for 1 site leave Foreign key inside Asset model and remove one Site model.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Asset(models.Model):
    site = Models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

-

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class UpdatedSite(Site):
     pass
```

Also, I would suggest you  read bit more regarding database relationships

Comment: My question specifically states that I do not want a ForeignKey in both directions. I want it on the Site model.

Comment: I don't think you had time to read my answer in less than 30 seconds through with understanding. I was referring to state your code currently is, so please be kind and read the whole answer.

Comment: I have increased the specificity of my question to 11.

Comment: If I try this I get a `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady` when importing Site.